# Swift - UIView when done updating its frame?

Tags: swift, uiview, delegates

I have a `UITableViewCell` in which I add my custom view, say

```
class MyView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    convenience required init(size: CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        height = size

        // init my other sub contents [1]
    }
}
```

From my `UITableViewCell`:

```
let myView = MyView(size: 35)
contentView.addSubView(myView)
```

My problem: my other UI components in `MyView` depend on the `width` and `height` of `MyView` and it's too early to set their position in `[1]` because `MyView`'s frame is now `(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: height)`

Where should I put my other UI components in `MyView`? Is there a delegate in `UIView` that tells me: "Hey, the frame of the view is updated with its actual size."? (like `viewDidAppear` in a `UIViewController`)

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
override var frame: NSRect {
    didSet {
        //update your subviews
    }
}
```

In your `MyView` class. But really, you should just look into setting up proper constraints:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Comment: I printed out the value of `frame` in `didSet` and saw that it is called only once with its value: `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. It's not the size that I am expecting.

Comment: Then it's because you're not setting it yourself at some point. You're implying that the frame will change somewhere later - I've given you the code to be notified of that change, but it's up to you to make sure the change is made.